# Spectral theorem for completely continuous operators in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I am writing an article and would like to provide the reader with the proof of this theorem (or a reference to literature where the complete proof appears), otherwise, I cannot quote it, nor use it. Can you supply either the proof or the textbook reference of it?

**Theorem**: *Let $A$ be a densely defined self-adjoint operator in a complex separable Hilbert space. Then the set of its eigenvectors form a countable orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space iff either A is completely continuous, or its resolvent $\rho(A)$ is completely continuous.*

So there are two possibilities, the second one covering the case in which $A$ is unbounded (which is typically the case in practice).

Comment: [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+operator) seems to say that in Hilbert spaces, completely continuous is equivalent to compact.

Comment: Absolutely, so a reference for a proof? :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem Wiki refers to some standard texts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It did not work so much as directly searching Google for „spectral resolvent”. :-)